# How can I get multiple event values in single return

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get multiple return values in a single return.

```
$('#Tbl :checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {

    checkedRows.push(
    $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
          return $(this).text(),$(this).find(".inputDate").val(),$(this).find('select').val();
      }).get()
    ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object literal notation something like below:

```
return {
   prop1: $(this).text(),
   prop2: $(this).find(".inputDate").val(),
   prop3: $(this).find('select').val()
}
```